# About sums similar to gauss sums

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic, roots-of-unity, gauss-sums

It is well known the case for sums like:
$$
  \sum_{i=0}^{p^n -1}\zeta^{-ai},
$$ where zeta is a primitive $p^n$-rooth of $1$.
But, is there a standard formula for sums like:
$$
  \sum_{i=0}^{p^n -1}i^N\zeta^{-ai}
$$
where $N$ is a fixed integer? 
Do you know references? Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Look up the formula for $\sum_{i = 0}^{m-1} i^Nx^i$ and then set $m=p^n-1$ and $x=\zeta^{-a}$.

Comment: Start with a finite geometric series $1+x+\ldots+x^{m-1}$ and repeatedly differentiate and multiply by $x$ to make $x^i$ have coefficients that are powers of $i$.

Comment: @KCd I think to have found the formula for when $i^N $ is costant but the general formula seems quite complicated

Comment: I have no idea what "when $i^N$ is constant" means ($i$ is changing, so it's not constant), but in any case sure, the formula is quite complicated.  There's no reason to expect tidy formulas for such things as $N$ grows.

Comment: @KCd I mean in the case when $i^N =c$ it's a simpler case. In general i think that it is not  really possibile give a formula. In fact i think that it does not exists formulas for  $\sum_i i^N$ too.

Comment: I don't know what $i^N = c$ means: $c$ is fixed?  The equation $i^3 = 5$ for $i = 0, 1, \ldots, 9$ doesn't make sense.  Concerning $\sum_i i^N$, there absolutely *is* a formula for this no matter what positive integer $N$ is.  To begin at $N=1$,  $\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} i = (m-1)m/2$. For $N > 1$, look up Faulhaber's formula.